# compare two text (one from Button, compare after click it), Android

Tags: java, android, xml

i am new in Android Studio, can you help me?
from fragment code below, i try to compare two text which one of it is from Button, after click *test_ans* button, will go to 'true' activity if they are same. But unfortunately the app is stopped :(

```
package com.xxx.xxx.xxx;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

private String mAnswer = "xxx";
private Button mButtonAns;

static {
    System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mButtonAns = (Button)findViewById(R.id.test_ans);
    mButtonAns.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mButtonAns.getText() == mAnswer) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, True.class);
                startActivity(i);
                //^go to true activity

            } else {
                //go to false activity
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

i tried delete *@Override public void onClick(View view)*, the *getText()* become red, is that *onClick* is the problem? please help ;(

Comment: for someone whom have same problem, please recheck your AndroidManifest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compare 2 string you need to use [equals](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) instead of `==`. `==` will compare the pointer of 2 `String` and `equals` will compare the value of 2 `String`

```
if (mAnswer.equals(mButtonAns.getText())) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: yea, looks better.. but the app still cant opened ("Unfortunately, XXX has stopped")

Comment: @eaglearms92 please share your crash log

Comment: ahh never mind, i didnt not declare on Manifest.. silly me, thx anyway :D

Answer (score 0):

```
if (mButtonAns.getText().toString().equals(mAnswer)){
    //do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `matches` for comparing String

`if (mAnswer.matches(mButtonAns.getText())) {
   ...
}`